# Is it possible to pass vendor credit application details in NetSuite's CSV import for vendor credits?

Tags: netsuite

I'm attempting to use the CSV import functionality to create a large number of vendor (bill) credits in NetSuite and would like to include the where the vendor credit should be applied so that our accounting team does not have to manually apply all of vendor credits.

However, in the field mapping in the CSV import assistant for "Vendor Credits - Apply" I only see three fields -- `"Apply (Req)"`, `"Line"`, and `"Payment"` I can't find anything in the documentation that can help me understand where I'd put the necessary information for the Apply when creating a new Apply (i.e. Vendor Bill ID indicating which vendor bill it should apply to and Amount of payment).

This seems to be a supported Sublist Data Import so it seems like this should be possible.

I've looked for fields indicating the information needed to generate a Vendor Credit Apply in the import (i.e. vendor credit amount and to which Vendor Document the credit should be applied) but there doesn't seem a way to pass them to NetSuite via the CSV importer. I'd expect to be able to pass in the necessary payment information to either create a new Apply record or change an existing one, but given the data model listed there of having a generic `"Payment"` field I don't see how that'd be possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- `Apply` should be the **internal NetSuite ID** (not external ID) of the document to apply payment to
- `Payment` should be the amount in $ to apply
- `Line` can be omitted or set to 0 in the case of application to a Vendor Bill, since the credit will apply to the header / entire Vendor Bill